# Compile Maven project using open liberty 21.0.0.8

Tags: java, maven, open-liberty

Up to version 21.0.0.7 it was possible to compile project sources by including Maven dependencies with the following Maven coordinates:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.openliberty.features</groupId>
    <artifactId>microProfile-4.0</artifactId>
    <version>21.0.0.7</version>
    <type>esa</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

But if I switch to version 21.0.0.8 not a single dependency is getting downloaded by Maven and build fails immediately.

Then I compared pom file of version 21.0.0.7 and 21.0.0.8 (public repo) but with no dependencies listed in pom file it is no surprise that nothing is really working at all.

So what do I need to change to get this running again?

Edit:

Output from Maven (command line not from IDE):

```
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/openliberty/features/microProfile-4.0/21.0.0.8/microProfile-4.0-21.0.0.8.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/openliberty/features/microProfile-4.0/21.0.0.8/microProfile-4.0-21.0.0.8.pom (1.2 kB at 5.6 kB/s)
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/openliberty/features/microProfile-4.0/21.0.0.8/microProfile-4.0-21.0.0.8.esa
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/openliberty/features/microProfile-4.0/21.0.0.8/microProfile-4.0-21.0.0.8.esa (16 kB at 40 kB/s)
```

With 21.0.0.7 there are 106 dependencies downloaded to local Maven repository folder. With 21.0.0.8 only the one shown above containing only esa file with property files and pom file without any dependencies listed.

Comment: Would help to post error messages from Maven (run from command line to get details if your IDE does not give any errors).  I added the 21.0.0.8 version of this dependency to a test project and it downloaded fine.

Comment: I have just added some more info.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for finding this issue - This is indeed a regression, and a bug has been opened to address this asap.  https://github.com/OpenLiberty/open-liberty/issues/18244

For now when using the all feature bom - use 21.0.0.7

Thanks - Chuck